# Unix help moving lines 2 and 3 to the middle of line 1

Tags: macos, perl, unix, awk, sed

I'm trying to concatenate every 2nd and 3rd lines into the middle of line 1; before the last tab character in line 1 specifically.

Here is a sample of the data that i have as outputted by a terrible banking system. Every first line starts with a date in MM/DD format followed by a tab character and ends with a dollar amount preceded by a tab character.

```
05/04   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR    30.64
ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN
4885434317495585
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR    181.24
ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX
4885434317495585
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR    42.50
ESTABLISHMENT * IL
4885434317495585
```

As you can see, I'm trying to concatenate lines 2 and 3 and put them before the last tab character in line 1. So basically,

```
05/04   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR  ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN 4885434317495585    30.64
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX 4885434317495585    181.24 
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR ESTABLISHMENT * IL 4885434317495585    42.50
```

Hopefully this made sense. I've looked through a ton of posts here, and while they were all useful, most of them were about merging 2 lines together, or printing them into a file etc, but not sticking lines into the middle of another line. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's better to show what you have tried and the results of them first.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Stanley, it is always advisable to add 3 simple things in your posts. 1- sample of input, 2-sample of output and 3rd- your attempts in code tags `{}` symbol. We ask efforts of people to be added in their questions, as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl,

```
$ cat stanley.txt
05/04   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR    30.64
ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN
4885434317495585
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR    181.24
ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX
4885434317495585
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR    42.50
ESTABLISHMENT * IL
4885434317495585

$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /^(\d+.+?)\n(.+?)\n(.+?)\n/msg ) { $x=$1;$a=$2;$c=$3;$y=$x;$y=~s/.*\s([\d\.]+)$/\1/g; $x=~s/$y$//g; print "$x $a $c $y\n" } ' stanley.txt
05/04   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN 4885434317495585 30.64
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX 4885434317495585 181.24
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT * IL 4885434317495585 42.50

$
```

or

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /^(\d+.+?)\n(.+?)\n(.+?)\n/msg ) { $x=$1;$a="$2 $3";$y=$x;$y=~s/.*\s+([\d\.]+)$/\1/g; $x=~s/$y$//g; print "$x $a $y\n" } ' stanley.txt
05/04   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN 4885434317495585 30.64
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX 4885434317495585 181.24
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT * IL 4885434317495585 42.50

$
```

or

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while( /^(\d+.+?)\n(.+?)\n(.+?)\n/msg ) { $x=$1;$a="$2 $3";@z=$x=~/\s+(\S+)$/g; $x=~s/$z[0]$//g; print "$x $a $z[0]\n" } ' stanley.txt
05/04   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN 4885434317495585 30.64
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX 4885434317495585 181.24
05/07   DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR     ESTABLISHMENT * IL 4885434317495585 42.50

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(As it is advisable to add your efforts in your post so kindly do so in your post).

```
awk '
/^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/{
  if(value){
     print value,val
     value=val=""
  }
  found=1
  val=$NF
  sub(/.*/,"",$NF)
  value=$0
  next
}
  found{
      value=(value?value OFS:"")$0
  }
/^[0-9]*$/{
  found=""
}
END{
  if(value){
      print value,val
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
05/04 DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR  ESTABLISHMENT 941 00009415 MAYS LNDG * MN 4885434317495585 30.64
05/07 DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 055329 VISA DDA PUR  ESTABLISHMENT 555 5551212 * TX 4885434317495585 181.24
05/07 DEBIT CARD PURCHASE, AUT 050418 VISA DDA PUR  ESTABLISHMENT * IL 4885434317495585 42.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample data and result, a `harcode` way can be:

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR%3==1{left=$1 "\t" $2; right=$3}FNR%3!=1{left=left " " $1}FNR%3==0{print left "\t" right;}'
```

Another way (GNU awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}FNR%3==1{tvar=$NF;NF--;printf $0 " "}FNR%3==2{printf $0 " "}FNR%3==0{print $0,tvar}'
```

It's also strictly 3 lines a round.

If you have `ruby` on you system:

```
ruby -aF"\t" -ne 'case $.%3;when 1; tvar=$F[-1];gsub(/\t[^\t]*$/," ");print $_; when 2; print $_.chomp + " ";else; puts $_.chomp + "\t" + tvar;end'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;N;s/^(.*\S)(\s+\S+)\n(.*)\n(.*)/\1 \3 \4\2/' file
```

Append the next two lines to the current line and using pattern matching combine groups of string into the required format.